# Creating and binding different Groups with different type of items

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

When you create a Grid App as a Windows Store Application you'll get a grouped and hard-coded list of items. `SampleDataSource` manages that: the groups are `SampleDataGroup` and the itemtype is `SampleDataItem`.

My goal is to use more than one type of items, let's say: `SampleDataItem1` and `SampleDataItem2`. But in `SampleDataGroup` there is only one kind of list, called Items and it contains only `SampleDataItem` items. So I would like to use different lists for different items, like:

```
public ObservableCollection<SampleDataItem1> Items1 
public ObservableCollection<SampleDataItem2> Items2
```

How can I bind to different lists (`Items1`, `Items2`), not only the one called `Items`?

Should I set the Source of each Group? How and where?

I hope the description of my problem is clear or clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Create common parent class for `SampleDataItem1` and `SampleDataItem2`, then create a collection of the parent class.

```
public class SampleDataGroup
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleDataItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDataItem { }
public class SampleDataItem1 : SampleDataItem { }
public class SampleDataItem2 : SampleDataItem { }
```